# How to add li tags after the sub tag

Tags: jquery

I need to create the following HTML

```
<ul class="restListings searchResltsUlClass">
   <sub class="sub">RESTAURANT NEAR BY YOU</sub>
   <li vendor_id="1" class="usernewrestaurant">
      <h6>Raj Cool Drinks</h6>
      <p>Area,City,Stete</p>
      <a class="addtoLocation" title="Add to location" name="Add to location"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But currently it is creating the following HTML

```
   <ul class="restListings searchResltsUlClass">
      <sub class="sub">
         RESTAURANT NEAR BY YOU
         <li vendor_id="1" class="usernewrestaurant">
            <h6>Raj Cool Drinks</h6>
            <p>Area,City,Stete</p>
            <a class="addtoLocation" title="Add to location" name="Add to location"></a>
         </li>
      </sub>
   </ul>
```

The issue is that the li tags are being formed inside the sub tag .
This is my code which forms the above HTML

```
    var divhtml = $('<sub class="sub">RESTAURANT NEAR BY YOU</sub>');

    var area = response.userdetails.area;

    for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
    {
        if(response[i].area === 'undefined')
        {
        }
        else
        {
divhtml.append('<li  vendor_id="'+response[i].vendor_id+'"  class="usernewrestaurant" ><h6>'+response[i].vendor_name+'</h6><p>'+response[i].state+'</p></li>');
        }
    }
```

could anybody please let me know how to push the li tgas after the sub tag ??

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` is for appending to the contents of an element. Use `.after()` to put something after the element:

```
divhtml.after('<li  vendor_id="'+response[i].vendor_id+'"  class="usernewrestaurant" ><h6>'+response[i].vendor_name+'</h6><p>'+response[i].state+'</p></li>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , but it is appending empty  data   to divhtml

Comment: You really need to append it to the `<ul>`. `divhtml` can only contain a single element, not a sequence of elements. Or you should work with HTML strings instead of elements, and convert it all to DOM at the end.

Comment: Thanks is there any quick solution for this ??